# Expression expected android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to show my summary result in a textview is there any syntax to use other than return summary because I get an error of unidentified expression, and I dont know of any other syntax.

```
    //construct the summary size out of select sentences
    String summary = "";
    summary = summary + "• " + firstSentence +  System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator");

    for(String sentence : sentences)//foreach string sentence in sentences list
    {
        if(setSummarySentences.contains(sentence))
        {
            //produce each sentence with a bullet point and good amounts of spacing
            summary = summary + "• " + sentence +  System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        }
    }
    return summary;
}
```

}

Comment: TextView textView3 = return summary;

Comment: yes that is the issue

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @JRowan that is where I have the problem

Comment: Because it's nonsensical and invalid syntax. If you explain what you're actually trying to do, maybe we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in the following line:

```
 TextView textView3 = return summary;
```

You're trying to assign a `return` statement to a variable, which is not a valid syntax.

Please take a look at the [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), specially in the [assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) and [return](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) sections.